# Mounting to hollow wall through slate tile

Tags: drywall, tile, anchor, drywall-anchor

I have slate tile on a wall in my bathroom and I want to mount a couple of robe hooks on this wall.  My plan was to use a couple of spring toggles, as the wall is approaching 1" thick with the tile and backer board behind it.  There are no studs where I want the robe hooks mounted.

The problem I've got is that the two holes in the robe hook bracket are only 5/8" apart on center.  The smallest spring toggle available is 1/8", which requires a 3/8" hole to be drilled.  I'm worried that drilling a couple of 3/8" holes through the tile that close together - leaving only about 1/4" of tile between the holes, edge to edge - will cause the tile to crack.

I know I can offset the holes a little bit to leave more material between the holes, but I don't have much wiggle room there either without the hole being exposed outside of the hook itself.  At best, I might be able to leave 1/2" between the holes.

Any other suggestions from anyone?  I'd really like to get away with drilling some smaller holes, but as far as I can find, I don't have that option with any other types of anchors that I can find.  Or maybe I give up drilling all together and use some sort of adhesive?

This is the hook I plan to use[image]

Comment: Are the two hooks close to each other?

Comment: No, the 2 hooks will be about a foot apart.  Each one in the center of a 12x12" tile.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a toggle for one of the holes and a very small masonry screw for the other.  The toggle will be doing all the heavy lifting, the small masonry screw will just be there for looks and to keep the robe hook from rotating.

Spax and other brands make small screws that can be used for light loads in masonry without an anchor.  The smaller sizes require only a 1/8" or 5/32" pilot hole.  That would give you about a quarter inch between holes.

[image: Multi-Material Screw]

Comment: I had the same initial thought, but this doesn't eliminate the need for two holes. I still think I'd do it. JMK, spin fast and push slow.

Comment: The hole for the screw with the plastic anchor would be smaller, but now that you mention it, why not just use a Spax or similar?  Editing...

Comment: @batsplatsterson - Are you saying just use Spax or something similar for both holes without any anchors?

In either case, wouldn't I still need to drill a hole that's at least the width of the threads of the screw through the tile to prevent the threads from trying to grip the tile and chipping/cracking it?  So, a larger hole in the tile (say 1/4") that the screw would slide through, then a small pilot hole (1/8") in the backer board that the screw would actually then fasten to?

Comment: @JMK - I meant use one toggle one Spax.  With the holes 5/8" between centers, I think it comes to one 1/8" hole and one 3/8" hole with about 1/4" between the edges of the holes.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion.  This is probably what I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nicely detailed piece of wood as a mounting plate for the hooks

Recess the head of a toggle in such a way that the hook will mount over it and cover the head.

Even a small oval wood piece behind a single hook would look good.

Here is a quick image grab of what I’m imagining 
[image]

Or a version of this [[image]][2

If those are not options I’d use simple plastic expandable anchors [drilling precise holes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gITn7isydmY) for them and use a blob of epoxy behind the bracket.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option as the boss (a.k.a. my lovely wife) already had the robe hooks picked out and purchased.  They're small, simple and match the faucets, shower fixtures, lights, etc. and adding a block of wood is not going to happen.  :)

Comment: No access to the other side of the wall I guess?  Post a picture of the hooks . And I am very familiar with the boss veto thing buhleeeve me!

Comment: Correct, no access to the other side of the wall.  Here's a picture of the hook.
https://embed.widencdn.net/img/moen/umau9evoyl/y400px@1x/yb8803bn.tif.jpg?q=90