# Mounting a hair dryer holder to a tile wall

Tags: bathroom, walls, tile, bathroom-fixtures

I don't have space in the bathroom for the hair dryer and therefore wish to attach a hair-dryer holder to the wall. The walls have tiles on them.

**Example:**

http://www.hood.de/i/foenhalter-foenhalterung-haartrocknerhalter-haartrocknerhalterung-foen-halter-85090377.htm .

Does anyone have any experience ?

What should be done and what should be avoided ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mounting to hollow wall through slate tile](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/148899/mounting-to-hollow-wall-through-slate-tile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to mount in on a tiled wall you need to drill a hole in the tile without cracking the tile.

I use a diamond encrusted hole saw and water like [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/QEP-5-16-in-Diamond-Hole-Saw-with-Water-Delivery-System-10571/311091628?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-311091600-_-311091628-_-N).

[image]

Go slow and you will have clean holes you can then insert  anchors into.

[This type of anchor](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Cobra-2-Pack-1-5-8-in-x-3-8-in-Dia-Standard-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3029084) should be sufficient since you have tile on the wall providing rigidity.

( *Sized appropriately for the hole size you create.* )

If you are lucky, *or plan it*, you may have a stud where you are mounting the holder. If so then you do not need the anchors, just screw into the stud.

Comment: Hmm, i don't, but i reloaded the link. Homedepot Store SKU #1004797345

Answer (score 0):

You put a wood block that fits behind it as big as will fit.   Silicone the wood block to the tile, screw the attachment into the wood block.  Done.  Not ruining the tile, good install.